# Is there a way to access an elements parent in tritium?

Tags: css-selectors, moovweb, tritium

for example, let's say there was this html:

```
<div>
  <div id="divchild"></div>
</div>
```

Would there be a way to access the parent div from the child elements namespace such as:

```
$$('#divchild'){
  # Access parent div here
  $$('< div'){
    # somethere here
  }
}
```

Is there a way to take the non working example and make it work? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

not with the css selectors.You'll need to use xpath selectors:

```
$(".//div[div[@id='divchild']]") {
    # something here
}
```

or

```
$(".//div[@id='divchild']/parent::div") {
    # something here
}
```

would select the parent div.